# Redshift function error - No module named boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create encrypt/decrypt on Redshift function somehow like [Encrypting and decrypting data keys - AWS Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html).

When I import boto3 in the Redshift function, I got error:

> ImportError: No module named boto3

Can someone help me on how to use boto3 in Redshift function?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aes_encrypt() 

RETURNS VARCHAR STABLE AS $$

  import boto3

  #encryption code here using boto3
  return 'my encrypt result'

$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you try to deploy / run this code?

Comment: Have u installed boto3 ? As per https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/ you have to pip install boto3

Comment: As I mentioned above, It's in Redshift Function.

Comment: Hi @NukalaRaghavaAditya, I am using Redshift, so I'm not sure how to import it in Redshift function?

Comment: You probably can't import external functions in an Amazon Redshift function. Why do you particularly need access to `boto3` within that function?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I am trying this instruction. Not sure I missed a step- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/programming-encryption.html

Comment: I think I can find some information here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

Comment: I can't see anything that says the `boto3` library would be available for use in an Amazon Redshift UDF.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [LIBRARY](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_LIBRARY.html) first. According to the AWS docs, Amazon Redshift supports Python version 2.7, so you will have to use boto rather than boto3.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Just change my mind when read this instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html  - "Important
Amazon Redshift blocks all network access and write access to the file system through UDFs."